# Custom Linked List in Java

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to implement my own LinkedList class which adds and deletes node. The only issue I am facing is, when I am trying to print all the nodes of the linked list, I am not able to print the last node because of my while loop. I am not sure how to remove this bug/error.

```java
public class LinkedList {
    private Node head;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList list = new LinkedList();

        list.insert(5);
        list.insert(10);
        list.insert(13);
        list.insert(15);
        list.insert(20);

        list.show();

        list.delete(13);
        list.show();
    }

    public void insert(int val) {
        Node node = new Node(val);
        node.next = null;
        if (head == null) {
            head = node;
        } else {
            Node temp = head;
            while (temp.next != null) {
                temp = temp.next;
            }
            temp.next = node;
        }
    }

    public void delete(int val) {
        Node temp = head, prev = null;

        if (temp != null && temp.val == val) {
            head = temp.next;
            return;
        }

        while (temp != null && temp.val != val) {
            prev = temp;
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        if (temp == null) return;
        
        prev.next = temp.next;
    }

    public void show() {
        Node temp = head;
        while (temp.next != null) {
            System.out.print(temp.val + " ");
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    private class Node {
        Node next;
        int val;

        private Node(int val) {
            this.val = val;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hint: figuring "why is my code not doing what I expect it to do" is a crucial part of learning programming. So: the very first step for you is to be able to **follow** what your code is doing. You can get there by A) learning how to use a debugger (really easy with an IDE like intellij or eclipse) or B) by simply adding PRINT statements. And then, also very helpful for such small pieces of code: take a piece of paper, and a pen. And then "run" your code mentally. Write down variable names, and then, write down what changes, etc.

Comment: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your code and I am only focusing your show() method so you can change like:

```
 public void show() {
        Node temp = head;
        while (temp != null) {
            System.out.print(temp.val + " ");
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

and this can easily captured via debugger.  I hope this will help you out.
For more please let me know.